# Dictionary key:value

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing

Is is possible for the value in a key:value pair to be a list? I'm trying to figure out a way to parse a big XML file efficiently. The general format is:

```
<things>
    <parameters>
        <various parameters> 
    </parameters>
    <thing id="1" comment="thing1">
        <nodes>
            <node id="1" x="1" y="1" z="1"/>
            <node id="2" x="2" y="2" z="2"/>
        </nodes>
        <edges>
            <edge source="1" target="2"/>
        </edges>
    </thing>
    <thing id="N" comment="thingN">
        <nodes>
            <node id="3" x="3" y="3" z="3"/>
            <node id="4" x="4" y="4" z="4"/>
        </nodes>
        <edges>
            <edge source="3" target="4"/>
        </edges>
    </thing>
    <comments>
        <comment node="1" content="interesting feature"/>
        <comment node="4" content="interesting feature"/>
    </comments>
</things>
```

in which there can be any number of "things" elements, each of which can have any number of "node" elements. The node elements contain voxel coordinates. I want to know which thing-voxel pairs are near other thing-voxel pairs. e.g., is thing 1 node 7 near thing 5 node 8? I don't want to bother determining the proximity of nodes in the same thing (e.g. I don't want to find whether thing 1 node 1 is near thing 1 node 9; the "edges" data take care of this).

Currently, I dump all of the data into a big list and go through the list using a bunch of for loops and if statements. It works, but it's slow, in part because it's moving point by point and continually querying whether the two nodes being compared are in the same thing. I figure that using a dictionary structure would speed things up, but I'm new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: The value in a key:value pair can be a list. As to your other question, how do you define 'near' in this case?

Comment: The answer to your main question is yes. A value in a dictionary can be any type, including lists or other dictionaries. You don't need to do anything special, just assign it as normal. Have I misunderstood the question or was that all the information you needed?

Comment: Thanks. It was a pretty general question, so this answers it. "Near" is within a threshold distance measured by the 3D distance formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#) from an XML string.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = """<note>
             <to>Monti</to>
             <from>Python</from>
             <heading>Reminder</heading>
             <body>Spam!</body>
         </note>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

You can then traverse your tree our use a dictionary comprehension to map the tags and text.

```
>>> {c.tag: c.text for c in tree.getchildren()}
{'body': 'Spam!', 'from': 'Python', 'heading': 'Reminder', 'to': 'Monti'}
```